# EXP a schema in Oracle 18c ORA1455

Tags: oracle

I have a schema inside a database that is not in a database as container in a version 18c of Oracle, I want to make a logical backup of this schema using the Oracle tool exp, I have a total of 2600 tables of these 16 throw me the error:

`EXP-00008: ORACLE error 1455 was encountered
ORA-01455: column conversion overflows data type integer`

Identify the tables and analyze what they had in common and I realized that they have a primary key autoincrement and they have at least one column of type CLOB, 14 of these tables are empty and 2 have data, already placed statistics = none at the time of the export but still still does not work, I have also tried to do it with the expdp tool but it always throws me the error that the .log file cannot be opened, I hope they can help me :(

Comment: It's hard to debug code without seeing the code.  Why not actually _show_ us your full, complete, exact 'expdp' command.  (There's no reason at all to be using 'exp' with 18c, unless you are going to be using the dmp to import into a very old version of oracle that doesn't support impdp.)

Comment: So I have tried to export:
expdp ari@orcl_sire dumpfile=ari.dmp logfile=exp_ari.log DIRECTORY=dir_prueba schemas=ARI

Comment: Do you have a reliable DATAPUMP tutorial that I can follow?

Comment: Complete, official documentation is at https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sutil/oracle-data-pump.html#GUID-501A9908-BCC5-434C-8853-9A6096766B5A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted, "exp" is replaced by "expdp". In terms of getting a schema level datapump export to work, you need the following:

1) A directory on the *database* server that you can write to.  And you need to create a directory *object* within the database to point to it, eg

```
create or replace directory MY_EXPORT as '/u01/myfolder';
grant read, write on directory MY_EXPORT to ARI
```

assuming "ARI" is the user that you will be connecting to when running your export.

2) A datapump command is then very similar to the old 'exp' command.

```
expdp ARI/ARIPASSWORD@ORCL schemas=ARI directory=MY_EXPORT dumpfile=ARI.dmp logfile=ARI.log
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you very much, I found that my error was the directory I was pointing to, I was directing it to any folder on my server, but when creating it pointing to 'C: \ app \ oradata \' I was able to use expdp

Comment: Note that when you create a directory object in the database, the os directory it references must 1) be mounted on / available to the database server and 2) have read/write permissions to the os user that is the owner of the oracle installation.